# How to deploy BIRT report on Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat7, birt

I have **tomcat 7.0.40** and have installed **birt-runtime-4_3_0** by copying the **WebViewerExample** folder in the **webapps** folder of Tomcat. I have **renamed** the **WebViewerExample** as **birt**.

I have copied the Report.rptdesign in the root folder birt and copied the java eventhandler jars in the **scriptlib** folder of birt. I also have copied the **sqljdbc4.jar** in **birt/WEB-INF/lib**.

When I try to run the report on the local tomcat server with the url:

```
http://localhost:8080/birt/frameset?__report=Report.rptdesign
```

all I get is the 'processing, please wait' progress bar running infinitely and do not get to see the report.

What mistake am I making? Please help.

P.S. The report is working perfectly in Eclipse environment.

Comment: These steps seem fine, check birt engine logs they should contain the reason of the problem. For example you might use a connection profile in Eclipse, which is not available under Tomcat.

Comment: I checked the logs. They are empty.

Comment: Did you also inspect tomcat logs? As you describe the problem it could be an OutOfMemory issue. Check memory settings for Tomcat JVM (heap memory and overall permgen memory).

Answer (score 1):

This may happen because of 'out of memory error'

Try to edit catalina.bat file under your Tomcat \bin

`set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512 -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256`

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

Download `org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar` file from apache website 
and paste the jar file to `C:\xampp\tomcat\webapps\BIRT\WEB-INF\lib` folder
and Working Fine For Me